# Adding advice around final methods in AspectJ

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop, final

Is it possible to add advice around a final method using AspectJ? I am totally aware that it is impossible using Spring AOP. But I couldn't find anything related to AspectJ.

Answer (score 3):

*Sorry for the introductory personal opinion, but I want to say this: You want to use AspectJ. **Why don't you just try?** You get a result much faster than by writing a question here and waiting for someone to answer it. Your question format is also unsuited for SO because you don't post any code you have trouble with, you just ask a general question.*

Yes, instrumenting final classes and/or methods is possible with AspectJ:

**Driver application with final method:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public final void doSomething() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().doSomething();
  }
}
```

**Aspect in native AspectJ syntax:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect MyAspect {
  Object around() : execution(* doSomething()) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    return proceed();
  }
}
```

**Aspect in @AspectJ syntax:**

I really prefer the native syntax, but anyway, for some unknown reason some people seem to prefer this ugly and wordy version with imports, throws, explicitly declared joinpoint instances and more complicated way to proceed:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Around("execution(* doSomething())")
  public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

The effect is the same for both aspect variants:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
```