# Spring AOP Advice for ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am new at Spring AOP. I try to write advice for ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException method to logging exception info. After hours of searching for solutions, I'm stuck.

This is my Apect component

```java
@Log4j2
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogginAspect {

  @Pointcut(value = "execution(* org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(..)) && args(ex, request)")
  public void callSpringExceptionHandler() {}

  @Before("callSpringExceptionHandler()")
  public void logBeforeError(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
  }
}
```

I have tried different patterns of pointcut but with no luck.
My advice logBeforeError does not ever called at all. Please help me with my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Spring documentation :[5.8. Proxying Mechanisms](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-proxying)

> If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface,
> a JDK dynamic proxy is used. All of the interfaces implemented by the
> target type are proxied. If the target object does not implement any
> interfaces, a CGLIB proxy is created.

and

> With CGLIB, final methods cannot be advised, as they cannot be
> overridden in runtime-generated subclasses.

[ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java) is an abstract class which does not implement any interface and [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2b1f229998422249eaee488777a9a9b8b04c05bd/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java#L124) is a final method. In short Spring AOP will not be able to advice that method execution.

You will be able to achieve advicing a final method using AspectJ though. Please go through the detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370667/4214241) from @kriegaex

Comment: @MadMax, I see you are still new on SO. Please be advised to accept and upvote correct answers instead of just posting "thank you" comments. This also would have the nice side effect of marking the question as answered instead of open. You accept an answer by clicking on the grey check mark beside it, making it green. Upvoting is done by clicking on the triangular "up" button.